# Windows 11, PhpStorm, PHP 8, Xdebug3, Docker Container, CLI - Path mappings are not configured for selected interpreter. Please check that mappings

Tags: docker, phpstorm, xdebug, xdebug-3

I had this working, but today when I tried to debug my CLI script, I am getting [image: click debug button]

And it does not debug. I have breakpoints that should get hit, but they do not. I do have path mappings set.

[image]

[image: Xdebug settings]

The Xdebug log is empty (in `/tmp/xdebug.log`)

If I listen for debug connection and debug with my browser, that works. So it is only CLI debugging that is not working.

Comment: *"The Xdebug log is empty (in `/tmp/xdebug.log`)"* But you have `xdebug.log_level=0` -- the lowest level, only critical errors will be logged. https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#log_level . The another one noticed config issue is not that important (`xdebug.xdebug.discover_client_host`)

Comment: Cannot really comment on the actual issue (1st screenshot) ... except that it suggests me that the path mapping it is talking about should be configured in `Settings | PHP` (the actual PHP Interpreter config) and not Run/Debug Configuration that you are showing on your 2nd screenshot.

Comment: *"If I listen for debug connection and debug with my browser, that works. So it is only CLI debugging that is not working"* What Xdebug log has to say about it? Do you actually have Xdebug configured for CLI (your system may use different php.ini for web server and CLI)

Comment: I have the exact same issue, and I can't find a configuration to change, Everything seems to be after the last phpstorm update, but have no proof for it.